# Formatting x_scale in ggplot with weekly data

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my `ggplot`, I've managed to create a `x_scale` based on time (I have weekly data) but am not sure how to create year-month labels using `scale_x_date`

The following is my code - I have tried using `(...breaks = "1 month")` and `(...minor_breaks = "1 month")` but this does not produce the desired result.  I am aiming for the labels to simply be `Dec-16`, `Jan-17`, `Feb-17` and so on.  What is the proper formatting to make the x_scale to show `Month-Year` in an abbreviated way?

```
ggplot(data=test, aes(x=as.Date(test$weekly), y=test$dist, group=1)) +
  geom_path(col = "blue") +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%Y"))
```

Here is a sample of the data

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(weekly = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(18L, 25L, 1L, 
8L, 15L, 22L, 29L, 5L, 12L, 19L, 26L, 3L, 10L, 17L, 24L, 31L, 
7L, 14L, 21L, 28L, 5L, 12L, 19L, 26L, 2L, 9L, 16L, 23L, 30L, 
6L, 13L, 20L, 27L, 6L, 13L, 20L, 27L, 3L, 10L, 17L, 24L, 1L, 
8L, 15L, 22L, 29L, 5L, 12L, 19L, 26L, 3L, 10L, 17L, 24L, 31L), 
    mon = c(6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), 
    year = c(116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 
    116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 
    116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 
    117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 
    117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 
    117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 117L), wday = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), yday = c(199L, 206L, 213L, 
    220L, 227L, 234L, 241L, 248L, 255L, 262L, 269L, 276L, 283L, 
    290L, 297L, 304L, 311L, 318L, 325L, 332L, 339L, 346L, 353L, 
    360L, 1L, 8L, 15L, 22L, 29L, 36L, 43L, 50L, 57L, 64L, 71L, 
    78L, 85L, 92L, 99L, 106L, 113L, 120L, 127L, 134L, 141L, 148L, 
    155L, 162L, 169L, 176L, 183L, 190L, 197L, 204L, 211L), isdst = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), zone = c("CEST", "CEST", 
    "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
    "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CET", "CET", "CET", 
    "CET", "CET", "CET", "CET", "CET", "CET", "CET", "CET", "CET", 
    "CET", "CET", "CET", "CET", "CET", "CET", "CET", "CET", "CET", 
    "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
    "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
    "CEST", "CEST", "CEST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
"zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), dist = c(23621.19, 
30400.01, 27458.66, 24511.07, 24908.37, 24413.81, 21096.52, 24557.51, 
14833.71, 15513.72, 13516.23, 8102.02, 5881.44, 8370.01, 7339.34, 
7703.79, 9297.52, 4542, 3555.56, 4438.33, 1968.65, 2259.06, 2729.89, 
2876.66, 1767.86, 784.17, 2004.55, 4446.98, 2203.16, 3956.35, 
4095.28, 3999.88, 3288.59, 4593.19, 6164.63, 6111.46, 8462.84, 
7404.8, 9725.91, 9652.72, 9357.52, 15535.51, 11810.82, 17890.89, 
23518.06, 18754.44, 16377.46, 15023.27, 23354.14, 23328.12, 27024.1, 
23414.38, 28273.08, 24213.3, 19068.03)), .Names = c("weekly", 
"dist"), row.names = c(NA, -55L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Perhaps use `date_breaks = "1 month"` instead? Read the [docs](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html) carefully. You can also use `date_labels` and not `labels`.

Comment: if you want to use `breaks` or `labels` you cannot use `"1 month"` you should define the dates and labels in a list or data.frame and feed them to the function.